# Помогите составить DQL запрос на основе SQL запроса

Tags: symfony

Подскажите как составить DQL запрос если есть SQL запрос

```
SELECT * 
from content_block_content cbc 
LEFT JOIN content_block cb 
       ON cb.id = cbc.block_id 
where cbc.lang = 'en';
```

Пробовал так

```
$result = $this->createQueryBuilder('cb');
$result->from('App\Entity\ContentBlock', 'cb');
$result->from('App\Entity\ContentBlockContent', 'cbc');
$result->leftJoin('cb.id = cbc.block_id','');
```

Но пока какая то ересть получается, подскажите как сделать?

Comment: Ну если знаете текст запроса, так и используйте `$entityManager->createQuery('текст запроса')->getResult();`.

Comment: Ну это вроде как не пофэншую, да и потом, если приходится подставлять кучу параметров were то код превращается - в плохой код...

Comment: Ну будет `$entityManager->createQuery('текст запроса')->setParameter(параметр, значение)->getResult();`... и, если надо для красоты да сопровождаемости - не в одну строку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таки сам додумался, если кому интересно:

```
$result = $this->createQueryBuilder('cb');
$result->leftJoin('App\Entity\ContentBlockContent','cbc','WITH','cb.id = cbc.block_id');
$result->getQuery()->getResult();
```